# extra parameter from dropdown passed to controller for new object creation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one object @Files which comes from (I took out all the checks , to make it shorter):

```
@idFiles = params[:file_ids]
@Files = File.find(@idFiles)
```

For each @Files I want to duplicate / and .create , but on top of that , I want to add the option that is selected by the user :

```
@Files.each do |fc|
FileTemp.create(:filename => fc.name , :selectedOption => fc.myOption)
```

The thing is in my view I have 1 (selected) 'myOption' value for each element of @Files:

```
<% @Files.each do |f| %>
<td><%= f.name %></td>
<td><%= f.path %></td>
[...]
<%= select_tag f.myOption , options_for_select(f.MultipleOptions.split(";")) %>
<% end %>
```

But I can't figure out how to pass that selected Value to my Controller, so as to create my new 'FileTemp' object

Many thanks in advance (I've been blocked for weeks..)

PS. initially I meant to update that value (without having to re-create another object) using Ajax perhaps, but I thought this way would have been easier.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out a simple example for passing an extra parameter via a select_tag.

In my form I just add the select_tag call I need for example

```
<div class="field">
  <%= select_tag :any_name, options_for_select([1, 2]) %>
</div>
```

If I now submit the form you can see in development log the parameters that are passed.

```
Parameters:
{ ... "any_name" => "1", "product" => { ... }, "commit"=>"Create Product" }
```

Now I get params[:any_name] in the requested controller action.

You must decide what fits your needs. Investigate further [here in Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)

Comment: Thanks for this krabbi, thing is it's not a form_for (it's just a Do loop). I loop through my files and want to update only one parameter, that's why.

Comment: Hm maybe I don't get your requirements but you usually request a controller action. For example with either a link or a form submission (or any javascript behaviour). And so you have to create a link or form with the correct request. There you have to pass the needed parameters.